# Multiple Protection Enchantments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to stack multiple protection enchantments on the same piece of armor? (an armor piece with both protection and blast protection, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get two Protection enchantments on one item with vanilla enchantment or using books. You can do this using the `/give` or `/summon` command though (this command will give the nearest player iron leggings with Protection III and Feather Falling I):

```
give @p iron_leggings 1 0 {ench:[{id:0,lvl:3},{id:1,lvl:1}]}
```

Look at [another answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/158546/69242) to get more information how the command works.

The enchantment IDs can be found on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Enchantments).

Answer (score 0):

No. A piece of armour can only have one type of protection on it in vanilla Minecraft. (Feather Fall on boots is not counted as a protection for this.)