# How do I give myself a specific sword using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've heard that there is a command that gives me the ability to give myself a sword with Sharpness 32767 and Knockback 32767. How do I use commands to give myself said sword on a server that uses the Essentials mod?

Answer (score 7):

See this: [Is it possible to add multiple enchantments in one try?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158532/possible-to-add-multiple-enchantments-in-one-try)

Also, this should work:

`/give yourname diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:32767},{id:19,lvl:32767}]}`
Don't forget to change "yourname" with your username.

Also you can see [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sword#Data_values) for the sword data values (diamond_sword) and see the enchantment ids from [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Enchantments) (16 and 19).

Answer (score 0):

There are Custom sword generators use one of those and put it in a command block /give @p minecraft:command_block and then you have the sword you wanted

Answer (score -3):

If your server has the Tim The Enchanted plugin you can get a sword with all merchants 1000. Using the /enchant command while holding the sword. Hope it helps!